# get average column A based on a range of values in column B

Tags: r, average

My dataframe has several columns as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,4), B=c(1,3,1), C=c(1,1,3))
```

I have two conditions to get average values for column A.

- Condition 1: I want to get average of column A when B is 1, i.e. only row1 and row2 will be averaged.
- Condition 2: I want to get average of column B when column A's values are larger than 1 but smaller than 3, i.e. only row 2 will be considered.

I know I can use filter to cut the dataframe to have column B = 1 only.  However, I am unsure how to do it when I want the column B to be considered as a range within 1 and 3.

Are there any smarter ways to get the average values of column without cutting the dataframe into a smaller size first?

Comment: On condition 1: `B == 1` in rows 1 and 3, not 1 and 2. Is this a typo?

Comment: see also `?cut` and `?tapply` or `?aggregate` or...

Answer (score 8):

You can do your subsetting in the same call to `mean` like so:

```
with(df1, mean(A[B == 1]))

with(df1, mean(B[A > 1 & A < 3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two logical tests with `&`. So you could combine the `B > 1` test with `B < 3`:

```
# Condition A:
mean(df1$A[df1$B==1])

# Condition B:
mean(df1$B[df1$A>1 & df1$A<3])
```