# R: mean when conditions got NA

Tags: r

Thanks for the previous posts and professional responses.  I can almost do my analysis, except those conditions with NA.  Here is my `data.frame` and code used.  Could you mind to teach me how to solve the problem when condition contains NA value?

```
 df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,4, 5), B=c(1,3,NA,1), C=c(1,1,3, NA), D=c(1,1,2,2))
```

Using this code, I get df1 as follows:

```
  A  B  C D
1 1  1  1 1
2 2  3  1 1
3 4 NA  3 2
4 5  1 NA 2
```

With the helps from Andrie, Sacha Epskamp and Chase ([R: get average column A based on a range of values in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138052/r-get-average-column-a-based-on-a-range-of-values-in-column-b)), I got mean values of A when D is between 1 and 3, i.e. 2 in this case, with this code.

```
mean(df1$A[df1$D>1 & df1$D<3])
```

I got my answer as 4.5 as expected (averge of 4 and 5 in column A).

However, when I replace column D to column C, which contains NA.  My answer could only be NA. while I was expecting to see the answer to be average 1 and 2, by neglecting the 3rd row (larger than 2) and the 4th row (with NA) in column C.

```
mean(df1$A[df1$C>0 & df1$C<2])

R> NA (i expect the count to be 1.5)
```

I know `na.omit` can remove all rows with `na` in any entries in `df1`. However, I prefer not to do so, as I would also like to get the mean and counts for every columns, when one columns' entry is NA. (e.g. I also want to do mean(df1$A, [is.na(df1$C)]) analysis.

I also tried to test using `na.rm=T` in the condition part, but R did not recognize it, as now the NA is in the condition part. For instance:

```
mean(df1$A[df1$C>0 & df1$C<2, na.rm=T])

Error in df1$A[df1$C > 0 & df1$C < 2, na.rm = T] :
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I believe there are smarter way of doing this.  Pls kindly advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R script - removing NA values from a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706876/r-script-removing-na-values-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 12):

The reason why you were getting an error stating incorrect number of dimensions was because the `na.rm=TRUE` was inside the square brackets. Thus, R was interpreting this as being the 3rd dimension of an object such as a dataframe, matrix, etc.  If the `na.rm=TRUE` is placed outside, it works fine.

```r
mean(df1$A[df1$C>0 & df1$C<2],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.5
```

Comment: Hi, I am going to do the same thing but I need to find the mean of every 10 rows of one column of my data (which has 1000 rows and some NA data) how should I do it?Can you please guide me?Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Shalen, I recommend you open a new question for this. If I understand correctly, your problem might be solved by creating a second column which groups the first column into blocks of ten rows (--> in the second column the first ten rows all get the value "1", rows 11-20 get the value "2" and so on). Then you use dplyr's group_by(second_column) and summarise(mean_of_blocks = mean(first_column, na.rm))