# Remove NA values from a vector

Tags: r, na, r-faq

I have a huge vector which has a couple of `NA` values, and I'm trying to find the max value in that vector (the vector is all numbers), but I can't do this because of the `NA` values.

How can I remove the `NA` values so that I can compute the max?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Trying `?max`, you'll see that it actually has a `na.rm =` argument, set by default to `FALSE`. (That's the common default for many other R functions, including `sum()`, `mean()`, etc.)

Setting `na.rm=TRUE` does just what you're asking for:

```
d <- c(1, 100, NA, 10)
max(d, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you do want to remove all of the `NA`s, use this idiom instead:

```
d <- d[!is.na(d)]
```

A final note: Other functions (e.g. `table()`, `lm()`, and `sort()`) have `NA`-related arguments that use different names (and offer different options). So if `NA`'s cause you problems in a function call, it's worth checking for a built-in solution among the function's arguments. I've found there's *usually* one already there.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. It fails and gives `-Inf` for a `d` of all NAs.

Comment: @user3932000 Just to be clear for others, your complaint is really about how the base R function `max()` behaves (as, for instance, when doing `max(c(NA, NA)`). Personally, I think its behavior is reasonable; I expect it was constructed that way so that you get the expected result when doing things like `a <- c(NA, NA); b <- 1:4; max(c(max(a, na.rm = TRUE), max(b, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @user3932000 Somewhat tangentially, one of R's many strengths as a data analysis platform is its sophisticated handling of missing data, the result of **much** careful thought on the part of its authors. (If you're interested in the subject, [see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/neps/missing-data.html) for a good discussion of some of the issues involved, from the point of view of programmers who were engaged in incorporating R-like `NA`-handling facilities in Python's excellent **NumPy** package.)

Comment: @user3932000: is that answer really bad? What would you consider the maximum of the null set?

Comment: @CliffAB It doesn't have a maximum. You can assign the max to be -∞ (and min to be +∞), but that's not always desired or intuitive. Also, when you remove all `NA`s from a vector of `NA`s, you would expect an empty vector, not -∞.

Comment: @user3932000: I suppose one might think they want whatever from `max(NULL)`, but `-Inf` is a very mathematically consistent answer to me

Answer (score 113):

The `na.omit` function is what a lot of the regression routines use internally:

```
vec <- 1:1000
vec[runif(200, 1, 1000)] <- NA
max(vec)
#[1] NA
max( na.omit(vec) )
#[1] 1000
```

Answer (score 51):

Use [`discard` from **purrr**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/keep.html) (works with lists and vectors).

```
discard(v, is.na)
```

The benefit is that it is easy to use pipes; alternatively use the built-in subsetting function `[`:

```
v %>% discard(is.na)
v %>% .[!is.na(.)]
```

Note that `na.omit` does not work on lists:

```
> x <- list(a=1, b=2, c=NA)
> na.omit(x)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 27):

`?max` shows you that there is an extra parameter `na.rm` that you can set to `TRUE`.

Apart from that, if you *really* want to remove the `NA`s, just use something like:

```
myvec[!is.na(myvec)]
```

Comment: I think this is best.  na.rm and na.omit add quite a bit of junk to the output.

Comment: Except `na.omit` also has a dataframe method, so is more general.

Answer (score 19):

Just in case someone new to R wants a simplified answer to the original question

> How can I remove NA values from a vector?

Here it is:

Assume you have a vector `foo` as follows:

```
foo = c(1:10, NA, 20:30)
```

running `length(foo)` gives 22.

```
nona_foo = foo[!is.na(foo)]
```

`length(nona_foo)` is 21, because the NA values have been removed.

Remember `is.na(foo)` returns a boolean matrix, so indexing `foo` with the opposite of this value will give you all the elements which are not NA.

Answer (score 16):

You can call `max(vector, na.rm = TRUE)`. More generally, you can use the `na.omit()` function.

Answer (score 6):

I ran a quick benchmark comparing the two `base` approaches and it turns out that `x[!is.na(x)]` is faster than `na.omit`. User `qwr` suggested I try `purrr::dicard` also - this turned out to be massively slower (though I'll happily take comments on my implementation & test!)

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  purrr::map(airquality,function(x) {x[!is.na(x)]}), 
  purrr::map(airquality,na.omit),
  purrr::map(airquality, ~purrr::discard(.x, .p = is.na)),
  times = 1e6)

Unit: microseconds
                                                     expr    min     lq      mean median      uq       max neval cld
 purrr::map(airquality, function(x) {     x[!is.na(x)] })   66.8   75.9  130.5643   86.2  131.80  541125.5 1e+06 a  
                          purrr::map(airquality, na.omit)   95.7  107.4  185.5108  129.3  190.50  534795.5 1e+06  b 
  purrr::map(airquality, ~purrr::discard(.x, .p = is.na)) 3391.7 3648.6 5615.8965 4079.7 6486.45 1121975.4 1e+06   c
```

For reference, here's the original test of `x[!is.na(x)]` vs `na.omit`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    purrr::map(airquality,function(x) {x[!is.na(x)]}), 
    purrr::map(airquality,na.omit), 
    times = 1000000)


Unit: microseconds
                                              expr  min   lq      mean median    uq      max neval cld
 map(airquality, function(x) {     x[!is.na(x)] }) 53.0 56.6  86.48231   58.1  64.8 414195.2 1e+06  a 
                          map(airquality, na.omit) 85.3 90.4 134.49964   92.5 104.9 348352.8 1e+06   b
```

Comment: you should try `purrr:discard`

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `complete.cases` like this:

```r
d <- c(1, 100, NA, 10)
result <- complete.cases(d)
output <- d[result]
output
#> [1]   1 100  10
max(output)
#> [1] 100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>