# How to remove all the NA from a Vector?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R script - removing NA values from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706876/r-script-removing-na-values-from-a-vector)

I could I remove all the NAs from a Vector using R?

```
[1]  1 NA  3 NA  5
```

Thank you

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `is.na` with vector indexing

```
x <- c(NA, 3, NA, 5)
x[!is.na(x)]
[1] 3 5
```

I also refer the honourable gentleman / lady to the excellent R introductory manuals, in particular [Section 2.7 Index vectors; selecting and modifying subsets of a data set](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors)

Comment: Or read `?NA`, which describes the behavior of `is.na` and lists `na.omit` in the _See Also_ section.

Comment: You can also use `s` from the package `hablar`. This: s(c(NA, 3, NA, 5)) return 3 5.

Answer (score 46):

In addition to @Andrie's answer, you can use `na.omit`

```
x <- c(NA, 3, NA, 5)
na.omit(x)
[1] 3 5
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 1 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```